# JQuery load and css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am loading some text dynamically into a div, but have the problem that everything below this div is moving around depending on the content loaded.

How would I limit the space belonging to the div with the dynamic content, such that the user only sees the text changing not the layout of the page.

thank you.

patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a height to the div with CSS.